# Zenoss Monitoring Templates, clearing events

Tags: monitoring, zenoss

I have a monitoring template set up on Zenoss to run a database query and use Nagios to check that the output of the query, which is a number, is within an acceptable range. When it's not, a CRITICAL level event is generated.

My question is: How can I make this monitoring template also generate a CLEAR level event when the output of the query **is** within the acceptable range. By doing this, any previously generated CRITICAL level events would be automatically closed once the device is running normally again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event transforms in the eventClass where the event is getting transformed and use de-duplication.

De-dupid is a combination of

device | component | eventKey | eventClass | severity

For Example Blade 7 pulled out from chassis 10.2.3.4 eventClass is /Hardware dedupid will be

10.2.3.4 | Blade 7 | Blade_Key | /Hardware | 3 [3 means warning]

**To clear the event all the field should be same except the severity**

10.2.3.4 | Blade 7 | Blade_Key | /Hardware | 0 [0 is clear]

[Event Tales Attributes](http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-12029)

check the link